# I'm designer but newbie in photography, Need Help for buying Camera, and How to choose between brands, lens and seconde-hand or new one?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-settings, photography-basics, camera

Recently I’m ready to buy a camera before I always use iPhone to taken photos, that’s okay but I want to start a series career you know, go art direction, street shoot, fashion series etc. 
I’m a designer, basically, but I’m a newbie in the photography field. So I’m indeed a bit confused about which camera choose.
I really need your help and tips.

However, I use the camera mainly for below directions:

- art direction
- street shooting (yeah I love street photography), travel,lifestyle etc.
- fashion shooting. I’m also a fashion style blogger,  fashion brands model and also my personal fashion brand model. So I need a camera for a lookbook something like this.
- taking photo shoots for my work so I can scan to the computer. I draw a lot, make collages, also make some craft objects. But the iPhone shots are not very clear and professional.
- I’m super love black and white photography. During past time I have taken lots of bw photos via my iPhone. Color photos also my type just more passion for bw though.
- I’m also passionate for shooting portrait, I’m planning start a long-term ongoing project that self portrait , to capture every moment of myself.
- I’ll set a mini-photoshoot studio scene in my home(mainly for art direction, work shoot, food styling, self portrait, my clothing line lookbook etc.  so any related accessories and tools recommend would be great as well.

So I have some questions and trying to solve:

1. based on my above directions, do you have any camera recommend?
2. What’s the most and core points when choosing a camera I should consider?
3. my budget is below $1800, $2000 is my upper limit. So is there any good fit camera?
4. Ideally, I’ll take the camera anywhere while I go out or travel, so I know lighter more better. BUT based on my above directions, do you think should I buy an SLR camera or Mirrorless camera？Any camera recommend?
5. I attached some of my fav photography, please forgive my silly question, but is this possible to see which camera they used? I love these style and color tone too much.  Here the reference [link](https://www.pinterest.com/nikistudio/for-camera-reference/): https://www.pinterest.com/nikistudio/for-camera-reference/
6. or, how about buying a second-hand camera body + new lens? If this possible?

Comment: `Questions seeking specific product or service recommendations, where the answer is likely to be either entirely personal or short-lived as a result of changing markets, are off topic here. Please rephrase your question to describe the problem you're trying to solve or what you do not understand that prevents you from determining the answer yourself. `

Answer (score 0):

Before I attempt to answer this I want to stress that generally, the most important thing in photography equipment wise is the lens itself or the glass. The camera body is indeed important but it's glass which is generally which will give better or worse results.

With that out of the way, Given your budget and my own personal experience, I would recommend looking in the second-hand market and looking at a Canon 80D (professional type) or a canon t7i (800D outside the US) - Once you have those you should hopefully get a kit-lens of 18-55mm. Other than that i'd highly recommend getting a 70-200mm lens for the work you've described.

That being said, I only have experience with Canon and when comparing the major brands from Canon to Nikon to Fuji they all have their pros and cons which is most of the time subjective rather than objective. Have a look at reviews, maybe if you have friends or family with cameras ask them to let you use it and see which one might be for you.

Hope this helps you.

Also, this might help you;
lenshero.com